# Cancel long running requests in ASP .NET MVC 2

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, parallel-processing, session-state

in my ASP .NET MVC2 application, there are two controller methods:

```
public class MyController : Controller{

public ActionResult Optimization(...){
    //long running optimization
    //this method writes to the Session

}

public void StopOptimization(){
   //user wants to stop the optimization
   //no access to Session needed
}
}
```

So in order to stop my long running optimization, the "Stop"-Method should be let through by ASP .NET MVC while the "Optimization"-Method is running.

I know that requests can be processed in parallel only if the SessionSate is at least set to "ReadOnly" for the whole controller class. I already followed the steps in [this blog post](http://blog.whiletrue.com/2010/09/asp-net-mvc-sessions-and-concurrent-requests-not-what-youd-expect/).
However, this implies that data cannot be written to the Session anymore, which is required by the Optimization-Method.

For this reason, I have decided to remove the "Stop"-Method from this Controller and put it in an extra Controller, for which I set the SessionState to "ReadOnly":

```
...
using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;
...

[ControllerSessionState(ControllerSessionState.ReadOnly)]
public class StopController: Controller
{
    public void Stop()
    {
         //Stop long running optimization
    }
}
```

However, the Stop-Request is still only processed after the Optimization in the other controller is completed.
Additionally I tried to implement a custom controller factory that allows to define the session state *for each ActionMethod separately* - this is described [here](http://sapoval.org/per-action-custom-sessionstateattribute). This has not worked for me as I do not use ASP .NET MVC 3, but only ASP .NET MVC 2 in conjunction with the MVC Futures Library.

Does anyone have an idea how I can implement a Stop-Method that allows the user to stop my long running method from client-side?

Comment: How about getting rid of the Session? Why do you need to use Session in those methods?

Comment: I maintain a Redo/Undo-Stack in the Session. Its a scheduling application. This means, before starting the optimization I push the old state of the schedule on the stack.

Comment: Can't you use Application state instead with some unique Guid identifying the operation? The unique Guid will be created when you start the operation and then passed by the client when you want to stop it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this means I do without the Session and instead store the redo/undo stack in the application state, referenceable by the GUID...

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will consider doing so!